# Displaying current and previous pay period in SQL (based on an imported table)

Tags: sql, period

I need to display the current AND last pay periods based on an imported table for biweekly pay dates. The table looks something like this:

```
2017-03-23 00:00:00 2017-04-06 00:00:00
2017-04-07 00:00:00 2017-04-20 00:00:00
2017-04-21 00:00:00 2017-05-06 00:00:00
2017-05-07 00:00:00 2017-05-20 00:00:00
2017-05-21 00:00:00 2017-06-05 00:00:00
2017-06-06 00:00:00 2017-06-22 00:00:00
2017-06-23 00:00:00 2017-07-06 00:00:00
2017-07-07 00:00:00 2017-07-21 00:00:00
```

**This code:**

```
     SELECT * 
     FROM 
       table1
     WHERE  
       (start_date <= now()  AND end_date >= now())
```

**Displays:**

```
2017-06-06 00:00:00 2017-06-22 00:00:00
```

**How can I display the previous pay period? 
Such as:**

```
2017-05-21 00:00:00 2017-06-05 00:00:00
```

This code just doesn't even look right, but I tried it anyways:

```
SELECT start_date,
CASE 
    WHEN start_date = now() THEN    start_date = now() - 1
    WHEN end_date = now() THEN start_date = now() - 1
END
FROM table1;
```

I know there is a way to use `CASE WHEN` but for some reason, I cannot get the syntax right using `now()` since I want it to be dynamic and not a static date.

Comment: Which sql database?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu could you please elaborate?

Comment: if no one will give you an answer i can probably write but later

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Shouldn't there be an easier solution using CASE and the current timestamp using Date (now())?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Throw your code at me anyways. I'll compare to what others post afterwards. And please try to keep it simple since I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT concat(start_date,'  ',
CASE
    WHEN start_date = now() THEN start_date = now() -  INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHEN end_date = now() THEN start_date =  now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
END) AS PeriodOfPay
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Your code shows everything in the table (same as mine, above). I need the last pay period to be shown. 
    2017-05-21 00:00:00 2017-06-05 00:00:00

Comment: I have edited the answer according to my understanding of your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

To get the current and previous pay period

```
SELECT start_date,
end_date
FROM table1
where start_date < now()
ORDER BY start_date desc
LIMIT 2;
```